# Can we say "visiting" a store when we mean buying things there?

Tags: word-choice

> He hasn't visited our store recently. I know he buys food in this
>   store. He has become very significant.

Does "has visited" go well with this context?

Is it suitable here, or should I have chosen another verb?

Comment: I don't think _significant_ in your last sentence is a good choice of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "He hasn't visited" is correct and idiomatic. Another option for a more casual tone would be "He hasn't been to our store recently." or "He hasn't come to our store recently." which can sometimes slightly differ in nuance based on whether you are implying you were there or not, where "been" could imply you were not there and "come" could imply you were, though this is not always the case.